# Stop user from editing local working copy in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

Using SVN lock we can lock specific file or folder from committing to Remote Config in SVN but is there anyway in SVN to stop user even to edit local working copy .

For example; If user edit some file in local working copy and try to save using `CTRL+S` will get alert like you can't change this file as it is disabled from SVN .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). Just configure the permissions to deny file modifications. I think that's the best option.

I do not know why you can't use permissions, but with SVN, you could [configure locking policy with the help of the `svn:needs-lock` property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.lock-communication). Then add the [`pre-lock` hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-lock.html) to prevent users from locking files. This way, you will require users to lock files before editing, but locking is disabled.

Comment: is there any alternative solution using  svn ?

Comment: yes svn:needs-lock property is a proper solution. thank you @bahrep